# Calculating the odds of choosing 3 separate objects out of a set of 8, each with the same odds, in 5 tries

Tags: probability

Let's say you draw random numbers between 1 and 8, each with 12.5% chance. Drawing a number has no effect on the odds of subsequent draws.

Each drawing rounds consists of 5 draws.

What are the odds of drawing a 1,2 and 3 in the same round? It doesn't matter in what order they are drawn, or if there are multiple of the same number. The only requirement is that a round contains at least one 1,2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

METHOD $1$:

Probability of numbers $4$ to $8$ (excluding $1, 2, 3$) in one draw $= \frac{5}{8}$

In $5$ draws, $P(\neg \, 1,2,3) = (\frac{5}{8})^5$ ...(i)

Now probability of numbers $1, 2$ not drawing $P(\neg 1, 2) = (\frac{6}{8})^5$ ...(ii)
Same for $P(\neg 1, 3), P(\neg 2, 3)$.

If we subtract (i) from (ii), we get the probability where at least one draw will have $3$ but no $1, 2$.

$P(3, \neg 1, 2) = (\frac{6}{8})^5 - (\frac{5}{8})^5$

So, $P(1, \neg 2, 3) + P(2, \neg1,3) + P(3, \neg1,2) = 3 \times  \bigg((\frac{6}{8})^5 - (\frac{5}{8})^5\bigg)$  ...(iii)

This the probability of each number $1$, $2$ or $3$ drawing at least one's without the other two numbers drawing.

Now the probability of not drawing $1, P(\neg 1) = (\frac{7}{8})^5$ ...(iv)

Now we subtract from (iv), cases where a) none of $1, 2$ and $3$ draw (which is given by (i)), b) cases where neither of $1$ and $2$ draw (given by (ii)) and c) neither of $1$ and $3$ draw (again given by (ii)). This gives us probability of number $1$ not drawing but both $2, 3$ drawing at least once. Similarly for $2$ and for $3$.

$P(1, 2, \neg 3) + P(2, 3, \neg1) + P(1, 3, \neg2) = 3 \times  \bigg((\frac{7}{8})^5 - (\frac{5}{8})^5 - 2 \times (\frac{6}{8})^5\bigg)$ ...(v)

Now $1 - (i)$ will give us probability where one or more of $1, 2 \, $ and $ \, 3$ will draw at least once. We will subtract from it probability when one of them draw and probability when two of them draw as all three need to draw at least once in $5$ draws.

So our desired probability $P = 1 - (i) - (iii) - (v) = \fbox {0.07782}$

METHOD $2$ (not providing much explanation in this method as it is more straightforward):

Find probability of them drawing exactly once, one of them exactly twice while other two once each, two of them exactly twice while third once and then one of the them exactly thrice while other two once each.

$P(1,2,3) = 3! \times {5 \choose 3} \times (\frac{1}{8})^3 \times (\frac{5}{8})^2 $

$P(1, 1, 2,3) = 3 \times \frac{4!}{2!} \times {5 \choose 4} \times (\frac{1}{8})^4 \times \frac{5}{8} $

$P(1, 1, 2, 2, 3) = 3 \times \frac{5!}{2! \, 2!} \times (\frac{1}{8})^5$

$P(1, 1, 1, 2, 3) = 3 \times \frac{5!}{3!} \times (\frac{1}{8})^5$

Add them all up and you get the desired probability of $\fbox {0.07782}$.

Comment: Wow thanks for the very elaborate explanation! I was trying to get there using the binomial coefficient but i couldn't make it work, it makes sense now! Also the first method of mutually excluding all odds is clever, but i guess it only works for low pools of numbers. Thanks again!

Comment: @Wim you are welcome!